# async / await for Node.js https.get

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to simplify code with async / await

But have problems making `https.get` with async / await structure.

I am aware of how to do this with third-party modules but prefer the native node.js `https` module.

Below code doesn't work for me:

```js
async function get_page() {

    const https = require('https')
    const url = 'https://example.com'

    const util = require('util')
    const https_get = util.promisify(https.get)

    const data = await https_get(url)

    do_awesome_things_with_data(data)
}
```

This code working fine:

```js
function get_page() {

    const https = require('https')
    const url = 'https://example.com'

    let data = ''

    https.get(url, res => {

        res.on('data', chunk => { data += chunk }) 

        res.on('end', () => {

           do_awesome_things_with_data(data)

        })
    }) 
}
```

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-node-js-using-async-await

Comment: I think you call `do_awesome_things_with_data(data)` at the moment when data is not resolved. Just for debugging could you do a setTimeout of 1sec between the function call and the promise

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`https.get` doesn't return something that can be [promisified](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) as the signature of the callback doesn't match `(err, value)`, so you can't [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) it.

However, you can wrap the `https.get` call within a Promise, like so, then await when calling `get_page`

```js
const https = require('https')

async function get_page() {
    const url = 'https://example.com'

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let data = ''

        https.get(url, res => {

            res.on('data', chunk => { data += chunk }) 

            res.on('end', () => {

               resolve(do_awesome_things_with_data(data));

            })
        }) 
    })
}

// usage

(async () => await get_page())()
```

### Edits

I've updated my answer to include the note of `https.get` not being able to be promisified and moved the `require('https')` outside of the function call.

Comment: The problem is that `get` does not return something that `promisify` can wrap.  The OP was aware that a promise was not returned.

Comment: `require()` shouldn’t be used in an `async` function as it’s sync. It’s also bad practice to `require()` inside a function that would get called repeatedly, generally, the same goes for `util.promisify()`. They both should be moved outside the function.

Comment: Yup, both comments here are correct. I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: This is an elegantly minimalistic answer, but I don’t understand why the get_page function needs to have the async prefix. When I implement this pattern without that prefix, it works the same. My understanding is that async permits await prefixes, but you don’t have any, and Promisifies non-Promise return values, but you don’t return any.

Comment: That's correct @JonathanPool - by default, in this case, you don't need the `async` prefix because we aren't `await`ing. For consistency, and to let the next engineer know who's going to consume the `get_page` function, they'll instantly know this function returns a promise, and will require to either use `.then()` or `await`.

Comment: The code is missing declaration of 'data' variable, like so ```data = ''``` either before https.get function or before the whole Promise thing. Otherwise the resolve will complain about the data not being defined.

Comment: Thanks @Igor I've updated the answer to reflect the missing `data` variable.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of promisify, roll your own function, or use a 3rd party library.  Promisify cannot wrap what `https.get` returns.

```
// generic promise method for https
const requestPromise = ((urlOptions, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(urlOptions,
      (res) => {
        let body = '';
        res.on('data', (chunk) => (body += chunk.toString()));
        res.on('error', reject);
        res.on('end', () => {
          if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode <= 299) {
            resolve({statusCode: res.statusCode, headers: res.headers, body: body});
          } else {
            reject('Request failed. status: ' + res.statusCode + ', body: ' + body);
          }
        });
      });
    req.on('error', reject);
    req.write(data, 'binary');
    req.end();
  });
});
```

Then call it like this:

```
async function get_page() {
    const url = 'https://example.com'
    const data = await requestPromise({url, method:'GET'})
    do_awesome_things_with_data(data)
}
```

Or simply use a library such as `axios` to return a native promise, and also handle additional boilerplate cases.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I cannot make it work, would you check what I did wrong at https://runkit.com/embed/df2eku6jnxix please? Better yet, post a runkit link that works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```js
async myFunc = function {
    let url = 'http://your.data/file';
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var data = '';
        https.get(url, res => {
            res.on('data', chunk => { data += chunk }) 
            res.on('end', () => {
               resolve(data);
            })
        }) 
    });

    let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves
    doStuffWithResult(result);
};
```

In my case, I was fetching a .json file, so I actually used `resolve(JSON.parse(data))` to return cleanely JSON object.